# Bad practice and a lucky escape or genuinely safe -- eval fstring

Tags: python

One of the new devs has put some code in that does the following:

```
var_name = eval('f"' + format_string + '"', kwargs)
```

Just to clarify, `kwargs` are externally supplied, but `format_string` is under the control of the codebase.

I don't like it as it looks eminently hackable. However, I can't do it. The string `format_string` is a string of the form `"I have eaten a {cow}"`.

Anyone have any examples? I don't want to chuck this out just because  I "feel like it's wrong". If this is genuinely safe, and it looks on the face of it it could be as the string contents never gets evaluated; just the formatting and nothing else, then great. I'm just paranoid.

I've tried examples like

```
y = "{moo}"
moo = "print(5)"
eval('f"' + y + '"')
```

But I can't get any code to actually drop out of the string and run.
Note I'm not a hacker. This is my first foray.

Just to be clear -- the question here is:

Is the code safe? If it isn't safe, can someone provide an example input that will execute? I'm finding it almost impossible to find such an example and I think it is safe as it only produces a string.

Comment: Note that name resolution of format strings is done at source code compile time – using an f-string inside ``eval`` means it can only access global variables. Whether this is actually exploitable depends on whether ``format_string`` or ``kwargs`` are externally supplied – please edit your question to clarify this.

Comment: To clarify the close: The code ``var_name = eval('f"' + format_string + '"', kwargs)`` is neither safe or unsafe, it is *incomplete*. Whether it is safe or not depends on the origin of ``format_string`` and ``kwargs``. The question is unanswerable until it is [edit]ed to specify this.

Answer (score 2):

It works, I suppose, and if `format_string` doesn't come from the user (so it produces a known safe f-string), it's technically safe, just fragile; are you that confident you won't make a mistake? But it's a very strange way to do this. The saner solution is to just do:

```
var_name = format_string.format_map(kwargs)  # or .format(**kwargs)
```

which would behave the same for simple named placeholders. It's not technically as flexible, in that f-strings can execute arbitrary code to populate their placeholder, while `str.format` only substitutes positionally or by name, but in your example, you don't need more than that, and it's kind of silly to involve the whole `eval` machinery when it's not needed.

The reason your attempt doesn't work is that it's just substituting in the `print(5)` and returning the resulting string, but not executing the `print` itself; if you did:

```
print(eval('f"' + y + '"'))
```

you'd see the `eval` produced the string `'print(5)'`.